# How to find or create a brush like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I need a brush like this. I use Freepik for resources. But I can't find similar brush. When I search grunge brushes, I see results but those are kind of vector look. But the one in this photo looks like a torn paper and realistic photo.

[image]

Is there any quick way to create this in Photoshop or is there any keyword to find such results online?

Comment: To me, it looks like a brush effect that uses pressure and transparency. Something like you might find in a collection of particle brush, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to any stock site and look up "torn paper" — you can find many torn edges like this in either white or transparent background.

- https://www.shutterstock.com/search/torn+paper

Comment: Got it. But the another purpose of asking this question was to confirm whether its actually torn paper effect/brush? The results look pretty much same on Shutterstock, but they don't have those textures on it. I think that needs some blending with other resources?

Comment: @Vikas 
I also think this looks like a brush made from a real torn paper image. It would definitely be the simplest and quickest way of doing something like this. Why recreate it digitally when you can just use the real thing. You could even tear a piece of paper and scan it yourself if you don't want to go down the stock image route